# Use of "tactical" to describe objects

Tags: meaning

I see the word "tactical" used to describe objects. But I'm not sure what it is supposed to mean. It doesn't obviously flow from the usual dictionary definition of "tactical", which describes plans and actions.

The word seems to be used in a military, police or perhaps general combat context. I'm not sure if it would cover a general fighting context, such as street fighting.

Eg the following news article of 9-June-2022 describes a man as having a "tactical knife": [Armed man charged with attempted murder of US Supreme Court Justice Brett Kavanaugh - ABC News](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2022-06-09/attempted-murder-supreme-court-justice-brett-kavanaugh/101137734)

> The man, identified as Nicholas Roske from Los Angeles, was carrying a handgun he had purchased to kill Justice Kavanaugh, as well as ammunition, a **tactical knife**, pepper spray and other items, according to an FBI agent.

But the word doesn't just describe weapons. It may also describe torches/flashlights, backpacks or water bottle holders. There are shops that sell "tactical gear", eg [Tactical Gear Australia—Supplier of Police Military Outdoor Products](https://tacticalgear.com.au/). That web site has a banner that says "tactical; law enforcement; military; outdoor; survival".

So, the word seems *often related* to military and law enforcement, but not exclusively. What is the essential meaning of this usage of "tactical"?

Comment: It’s just a fluff word, like “professional” or “deluxe”. Don’t look for something that isn’t there. Army dressup is not the same as real army.

Comment: @GlobalCharm I can understand that it might be fluff for retail/marketing. But, how about the quote from the ABC News article? Is that a technical term that came from the FBI agent?

Comment: It’s more than fluff or dress-up. A tactical knife is a knife suitable for use in a defensive or aggressive purpose, not merely for cleaning fish after they have been  caught, or cooking dinner once caught.

Comment: … . .It has a purpose in an altercation, even among individuals.  The analogy is from military operations.

Comment: The extension of “tactical” to flashlights is partly a marketing tool, but also suggests that the item has features useful in a defensive situation—strength, intensity of beam, and the like.

Comment: Related: ["Tactical Language" (from the Police) is from "Tactical Warfare" (from the Military) etymologically?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/546796).

Comment: @GlobalCharm I don't think it's "just fluff" in "tactical nuclear weapon".

Comment: @HotLicks....Indeed...sadly, we need to think about this shit again. I remember going down into the basement to kiss our ass goodbye in grade school.

Comment: Do note that the word is easily confused with"tactile".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the word ***'tactical'*** is often mis and/or over-used, usually to appeal to wannabe warriors like Kyle whatshisname. A search on Amazon.com yields any number and type of equipment that is styled as 'tactical'...

However, the usage of the word used  only to apply to equipment that performed  **a specific offensive/defensive purpose...**

> : **of or relating to combat tactics: such as...**
> (1) : of or occurring at the battlefront a tactical defense; a tactical first strike,
> (2) : using or being weapons or forces employed at the battlefront; tactical missiles

[-Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tactical)

The [most extreme usage of the term is seen in "tactical nukes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_nuclear_weapon). These were designed for the battle front, but are admittedly a bit of overkill in tank warfare. (Expect to see more usage of this term in the near future.)

[By way of comparison,  we also see the term ['Strategic'...](https://www.britannica.com/topic/strategy-military) Many people do not understand, or cannot explain  the difference, and really has no bearing on the topic at hand...]

---

**So what does "tactical"  mean more recently?**

In the last 20-30 years, the term has been extended to body armor, as well as [MOLLE vests and other equipment](https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&) that attaches to these as  used in small arms tactics (such as knives). [See the second image below.]

***Knife Lore***

> *"The good knife fighter thinks on point and blade and shearing-guard
> simultaneously. The point can also cut; the blade can also stab;"*

[Frank Herbert (Dune)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel))

Knives have  many uses, but primarily they are intended for cutting and stabbing. Most people who look at knives with a civilian eye see only the shiny  tool that cuts their tomatoes. Professionals such as  Chefs think on the cutting edge, and butchers look at the tip, but also the edge.

Some  large knives are designed for survival in the field; this may include self-defense.

For example, to the left in the first image below, the heavy ESSE 5S is considered a **survival** knife. It was designed for [RAT SAR](https://eseeknives.com/blog/rat-sar), and made to chop its way out of a downed helicopter and also to survive in the field. It's primary purpose is to cut and hack ([see: batoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batoning)). It includes other features that are non-tactical. It is considered unbreakable, but some old hands may blunt the tip just in case.

The two knives to the right (Gerber StrongArm and Boker Nano L-R) I would consider  **tactical**; notice the **spear tip**. Its primary purpose is to provide maximum penetration. If you try to chop wood with these they might break. Tactical blades like these are often worn clipped to a Molle vest (see link above, and image below), or even hidden inside a boot.

This is my expert opinion...however, most civilians and even war correspondents may not see the differences, and probably refer to all of these as "tactical".

To make it even more confusing, many manufacturers are combining features , and often describing pretty much anything made for the woods and colored in olive, black or desert tan as 'tactical.

[image: knife image 1]

Below is an image of the Gerber clipped to a MOLLE vest.
[image]

Comment: If someone could help me edit to get rid of the empty space between the 2 images, I would really appreciate it....

Comment: I think you could fix them as follows: download the image to your computer, then upload.  If it's too large or has an unpleasant border, edit on your machine (e.g. with Irfanview).

Comment: @aparente001 I think I tried that yesterday, and ended up losing half the post! After 2 hours of revision!

Comment: Sounds like you might have highlighted too much stuff by accident.  I just replaced the first image with a screenshot of the first image without the extra white space.  I recommend that you avoid using google links.  Also, I recommend the Yandex browser extension that fixes google links. Also I recommend installing a clipboard manager (I use Arsclip but you might prefer something simpler), and then you can highlight all and copy periodically.

Comment: @aparente001 Thank you so much....I will certainly look at your suggestions...

Comment: @aparente001 BTW...that was not a google link. It was my own image..I covered up the serial numbers for privacy. I am a responsible owner, so they are registered.

Comment: When I edited the post, I saw a long, messy url that had "google" in it.  But I didn't take a close look.  By the way, didn't you want to fix the other photo?

Comment: OK...looks like I had a lot of empty space in the image from not cropping it well...

Comment: Very nice......

Comment: @aparente001 I just thunk a thought...if we post original images here, are we giving license for re-use? Considering we got bought out and all...

Comment: Sorry, no clue.  Maybe ask at the big Meta.

Answer (score 2):

Collins:

> **Tactical** weapons or forces are those which a military leader can decide for themselves to use in a battle, rather than waiting for a decision by a political leader: *They have removed all tactical nuclear missiles that could strike Europe.*

(I don't think the example really fits the definition they gave, but I thought the definition was interesting.)

[Collins, cited at freedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tactical):

> 2. (Military) (of weapons, attacks, etc.) used in or supporting limited military operations: *a tactical missile; tactical bombing*.

[MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/tactical):

> 3. tactical aircraft, missiles, and other weapons are designed to be used over short distances: *sea-based tactical aircraft*

From all of these I interpret **tactical knife** as being a knife designed to severely maim or kill another human being, to distinguish it from other types of knives.  Also I understand that a tactical knife is in the style of a knife that might be used in war.  (I know nothing about implements of war and would prefer to keep my head in that patch of sand....)

Comment: Dictionary definitions of *tactical* are of limited help to somebody who is trying to make sense of the usage of that word that has recently become widespread, particularly in the U.S. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the contrast between *tactical* and *strategic*, which was an aspect of its traditional meaning.

Comment: There are other dictionary definitions that seem more relevant, e.g. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tactical) "of or relating to combat tactics" or [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tactical) "Relating to or constituting actions carefully planned to gain a specific military end." You're right that a tactical weapon or item is somehow, however loosely, designed for use in combat or warfare (although in practice most will never see battle) but (as jsw29 says) there is more to be said about this sense, where it comes from, and how it is used.

Comment: @jsw29 - I agree that the tactical-vs.-strategic aspect appears to be irrelevant in this case.  And in the end maybe it just boils down to *tactical knife = really serious, nasty knife* or *military-grade knife*.

Comment: @aparente001 closing thoughts: Rambo used to carry a K-Bar, and so this knife was popularized in the movies and became a legend.... Although it includes all kinds of 'survival' items in the pommel, people like me consider this to be the last thing we would want to depend on in  the woods...and yet this is the image that most people have in mind when they hear "survival/ tactical knife". Unless maybe it is an Ontario RAT blade...

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ - I know nothing about knives except that where I live, young people sometimes tragically maim and kill each other with them.  The only curiosity I have is, what implement should I buy to get the rest of the scales off my salmon fillets, when the grocery store salmon hasn't been scaled properly.  Also where to buy one. I've been using a tomato knife but I have a feeling the right implement would make it easier.

Comment: [This is the tool I would use for fish scaling](https://www.amazon.com/Stainless-Shaver-Killer-Household-Killing/dp/B08YZB2JWQ/ref=sr_1_56?keywords=fish+scaler&qid=1655492449&sr=8-56), and it is not even a knife. Using a knife for scaling fish is messy...my father was a butcher, so I am quite comfortable with all types of tools for butchery. ///BTW, if people really wanna hurt each other and have no more-sophisticated killing technology, a stone or piece of wood will do in a pinch...

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ - Thank you, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Life hint...if you take 2 serrated steak knives and tape them together, you have a dandy fish scaler.

Comment: Okay, I need more info about that.  Maybe a video.  I don't know if they're supposed to be head to toe or what, and why that works better.

Comment: If and when I can figure out how to post my images in comment then I will do so. In the meantime, if you take 2 or 3 serrated steak knifes and tie them side-by-side with all points in the same direction, it is the same as the specialized tool I mentioned. Using a single blade to scale fishies is gonna leave scales in your hair....in my case, beard.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ - Oh, I get it.  Thanks.  I think I would use rubber bands.

Comment: [hand to head]...typical American here. We usually think on overkill, i.e. duct tape. Gotta dip, g'nite.

Answer (score -1):

*Tactical* can also be used ironically. Police in the UK often use a red-painted hand-held battering ram to force entry to properties, commonly called 'the big red key'.

In a recent police TV programme I was watching, an officer referred to the one he was using as having been painted 'tactical black'. Regrettably I can't remember the name of the programme.